# Is there a way to store an array of integer variables, into a single element of another array?

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

So instead of using classes, or structs, I want to use a 5 element array. I want to use these just to keep track of simple numbers, and using several identical arrays, I can treat each one as an "object". However I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to store the entire array, into an element of another array, and be able to access the sub array elements when needed. It's been a while since I've done object oriented programming, so I'm struggling at the moment.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into multidimensional arrays.

Comment: To store an array of int into one index of another array define this other array as an array of pointer to int.  https://onlinegdb.com/uMQskw-nr

Comment: Hmm, using that link, the code does exactly as I need it to. Using the game engine that I use, when trying to read it back, it's telling me the array is of the wrong dimension. The engine is looking at it like array is supposed to be two dimensional, but it's only defined as one dimensional. That's odd.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a two-dimensional array in c++. a two dimensional array is kinda an array of arrays, and can be declared like this:

```
int ar[4][3];
```

(this is a 4 element array and each element is a 3 element array)
it can also be initiated too:

```
int ar[4][3]={{1,2,5},{10,15,6},{11,1,3},{7,5,3}};
```

and you can access the numbers like this:

```
a=ar[2][3];
```

(now 'a' is the 3rd element of the 2nd array of 'ar')

I hope it helps!